# ld cannot find /lib64/libmvec.so.1 with g++ command

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm getting started learning c++ project building on linux with simple hello world code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"hello,world"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run command

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

It fails with:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libmvec_nonshared.a
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/ld: cannot find /lib64/libmvec.so.1
```

But when I try

```
gcc -lstdc++ hello.cpp
```

The compilation is successfully finished and generated executable file a.out.

So what is problem here with g++?

Comment: Where that compiler comes from? You compiled it yourself? Installed manually? DOes this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467726/compilation-error-ld-cannot-find-libmvec-nonshared-a-libmvec-so-1-while-using?

Comment: It was installed by other person. The server I'm using have 2 version of gcc(6.3.1/4.9.2). Both of them failed with the same error. Because there are other projects running on the server I can not change the gcc version.

Comment: When you compile a program with C/C++ you have to specify the libraries you are using to link against. In this case you need stdc++ because you are using std::cout. The stdc++ library probably has an internal link reference to libmvc. You could do an ldd against the working executable and then do the same against each library reported.